# Executing multiple it block inside a loop of Protractor and consume the variable in the IT blocks

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a situation where we need to do a for loop and then then consume the for loop variable for doing couple of 'it' blocks inside the for loop. A sample code is below:

```
   for (i=0; i <3; i++){
    it ('should complete the first test', function(){
        let j = i+1;
        console.log(j);

    });

    it ('should complete the first test', function(){
        let K = i+3;
        console.log(K);

    });
}
```

when I run this code, I am getting the following :

```
4
.6
.4
.6
.4
.6
.
```

But I need to have values 1,2,3 for the first test block and 3,4,5 for the second block. I saw there are many questions on SO on For loop issues,, but could not figure out a solution that can help me. If I wrap the functions as "return it(... " this only works for the first it block. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare your counter above your loops you should get the counts you are looking for.

```
describe('desribe the test', () => {
    let count = 1;

    for (i=0; i <3; i++){
        it ('should complete the first test', function(){
            console.log(count);
            count++;
        });    
    }
    for (i=0; i <3; i++){
        it ('should complete the first test', function(){
            console.log(count);
            count++;
        });    
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`it(...)` simply registers the test.  your `for` block will loop three times, registering six tests. Once your for block is done running, and `i === 3`, only then do your `it(...)` blocks run, and they log the value of either `i+1` or `i+3`.  In all cases, `i` will be `3` so `i+1` = 4 and `i+3` = 6

Comment: Thanks Joseph for the Explanation. However do you know any method that I can use to overcome this and log all six different values ?